# Оптимизация проверки и загрузки файлов через потоки

Tags: c#

Есть изменяющийся каждый запуск программы список URL'ов `List<FileInfo> URLs = new List<FileInfo>();`

```
public class FileInfo{
public string FileURL {get;set;}
public string FilePath {get;set;}
public string Hash {get;set;}
}
```

Мы проходимся foreach'ем по списку и кешируем файлы на наличие, если не совпадают с эталонами - загружаем.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, что бы запустить по потоку на каждый обьект списка, что бы они все хешировались и скачивались асинхронно, и что бы выполнение программы продолжилось только после того, как они все загрузятся?
P.S. Предполагаю, что это можно будет сделать через TaskFactory, но я не смог реализовать подобное.

Comment: Я так понимаю вы делаете некую систему автообновления. Как то реализовывал что то подобное, по началу обычными тасками, потом посоветовали `Dataflow`, реализовал и процесс загрузки стал в разы быстрей и грамотней работать. Так что советую ;-)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не знаю, посмотрел документацию ( https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline ) и у меня такое ощущение, что в примере, который там приводится можно просто вырезать DataFlow и ничего не изменится. Я не смог придумать реализацию, если предложите - буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал только подобное решение:

```
List<FileInfo> URLs = new List<FileInfo>();
Task[] LibrariesDownloadTasks = new Task[manifest.Libraries.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < URLs.Count; i++){
    LibrariesDownloadTasks[i] = new Task(() => ProcessURL(URLs[i].FileURL, URLs[i].FilePath, URLs[i].Hask));
    LibrariesDownloadTasks[i].Start();
}
Task.WaitAll(LibrariesDownloadTasks);
```

А в `private void ProcessURL(string FileURL, string FilePath, string Hash)`
происходит вся обработка.